# Is it possible to incrementally train a Haar-cascade with new training data?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, haar-classifier, supervised-learning

I have a cascading classifier in opencv that was trained with Haar features on about 400 positive samples and 3019 negative ones.
But this took quite some time to train, several hours.
Since then I've gotten fairly good results, and have about 480 more positive samples, and this will continue to grow.
To increase the performance of this cascading classifier, I wanted to use the increased set of training samples I now have.
Do I now need to retrain the entire cascade from scratch, or is there a way to continue from where I left off?

Comment: you can continue an old cascade classifier training and I'm sure that some of the parameters are changeable while others are not and probably you can always add additional negative samples. Why don't you just test whether chosing a different .vec file will work, too? You'll need the old training result directories, just having the .xml will not work. If continuing works, you'll see something like "loaded stages 0 to n"